# How to offload complex Firestore queries into Firebase Cloud Functions and parse results on iOS/Swift client?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So currently, my client (iOS/Swift) is fetching documents by filtering on a `whereField(...)` and then further filtering down the results based on a few other fields. This means that some objects are fetched, then discarded, wasting precious resourced and bandwidth!

**Can I do this complex filtering on a firestore cloud function than somehow parse the filtered results into the same firestore object on the client?** To be clear, I know how to write cloud functions that fetch and return documents, I am more interested to understand the transport method to the client.

Code snippet to provide some context:

```swift
static func unmatchedChatsHelper(cursor: Any?, promise: @escaping (Result<UnmatchedChatsCursorResponse, Never>) -> Void) {
    let earliestEventTime = Date()
    // (1) Filtering done on backend.
    var query = Firestore.firestore().collection("chats")
        .whereField("eventTime", isGreaterThan: earliestEventTime)
        .order(by: "eventTime")
        .order(by: "createdAt", descending: true)
    if let cursor = cursor as? DocumentSnapshot {
        query = query.start(afterDocument: cursor)
    }
    query.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let querySnapshot = querySnapshot else {
            fatalError("Query snapshot failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "no error")")
        }
        let transformedModels = querySnapshot.documents.compactMap { (chatQueryDocumentSnapshot) -> ChatModelFirebase? in
            do {
                return try chatQueryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: ChatModelFirebase.self)!
            } catch let error {
                logEvent(AnalyticsEventDidDropDocument, [
                    "document_id": chatQueryDocumentSnapshot.documentID
                ], error)
                return nil
            }
        }
        let me = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        // (2) Filtering done on client! This means some chats are retrieved unnecessarily. 
        let unmatchedChats = transformedModels.filter {
            !$0.participants.contains(me)
                && $0.numParticipants < 6
                && !$0.declinedParticipants.contains(me)
                && $0.isDebug == DebugGating.isDebugBuild()
        }
        let cursor = querySnapshot.documents.last
        promise(.success(UnmatchedChatsCursorResponse(models: unmatchedChats, cursor: cursor as Any)))
    }
}
```

I have three options:

1. *[My Choice/Best Option]* Same as above, but use `Firestore.Decoder` to parse results `ChatModelFirebase`.
2. *[Parsing Logic is Dangerous]* Do the query on a cloud function, return JSON, and manually parse the results into `ChatModelFirebase`.
3. *[Too Costly To Do]* Update my firestore document structure for all queries to be done via the `whereField(..)` but this is complex since `whereField` is limited in its options.

**Anything else I a missing? Is there a better way to do this?**

Comment: If by #3 you mean to update your stored data to make the queries simpler, I think you've pretty much covered all major options.

Comment: Yeh, exactly. Which one of the tree options would you recommend? My choice would probably be #1.

Comment: There is no singular approach that is best for all situations and everyone. I personally prefer to do no client-reads-from-cloud-functions ever, so I don't use #2. But that's a personal preference/trade-off, as I'm always trying to show the power of realtime updates/listeners. I have a soft spot for #3, but I'm always torn on whether to do the duplication/fan-out from the client, or by performing it in Cloud Functionsd.

Answer (score 0):

In case you end up keeping your current logic (filtering on the client), here are some tips so you can limit your documents some more.

1. You can't use `declinedParticipants` in a query, because queries can only ask "which documents HAVE this value", and not "which documents DON'T have this value". You can maintain and use a `notDeclinedParticipants` field instead:

```
.whereField("notDeclinedParticipants", arrayContains: me)
```

2. Since `numParticipants` contains distinct small integers, you can use a ['in' query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any):

```
.whereField("numParticipants", in: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

3. To add a range filter based on `eventTime` and run a [compound query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries), create a composite index that will include all the other fields that you need to put in your queries, plus `eventTime`.

Example (untested) code:

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("chats")
    .whereField("notDeclinedParticipants", arrayContains: me)
    .whereField("numParticipants", in: [2, 3, 4, 5])
    .whereField("isDebug", isEqualTo: DebugGating.isDebugBuild())
    .whereField("eventTime", isGreaterThan: earliestEventTime)
```